# EPPlus SaveXlsx throws Array dimensions exceeded supported range

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I am trying to save 90000 rows x 2000 columns excel file using EPPlus. The error is System.OverflowException: 'Array dimensions exceeded supported range.' From the doc Excel supports max columns `16,384` and rows `1,048,567`. Any idea please

```
using (var excel = new ExcelPackage())
            {
                var ws = excel.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("test");
                //ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromText(new FileInfo(csvFilePath));
                for(int r = 1; r < 90000; r++)
                {
                    for (int c = 1; c < 2000; c++)
                    {
                        ws.Cells[r, c].Value = r*c;
                    }
                }

                excel.SaveAs(new FileInfo(excelFilePath));
            }
```

The errors:

```
System.OverflowException: 'Array dimensions exceeded supported range.'
```

resolved by add into app.conf

```
<runtime>
        <gcAllowVeryLargeObjects enabled="true" />
    </runtime>
```

and the error:

```
OfficeOpenXml.Packaging.Ionic.Zip.ZipException: 
Compressed or Uncompressed size, or offset exceeds the maximum value. 
Consider setting the UseZip64WhenSaving property on the ZipFile instance.
```

still open.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/search?q=UseZip64WhenSaving&unscoped_q=UseZip64WhenSaving https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/blob/e7230ed0450ff9985b4c8a159f74ca1c348d6e67/EPPlus/Packaging/DotNetZip/ZipOutputStream.cs#L671